# Implement a Binary Tree using array

Tags: c, arrays, tree, binary-tree, abstract-data-type

in HW i am asked to implement a Binary Tree using pointers and then using the array implementation of bt. The problem is that while i know how to do both , they have to share the same main file . By that i mean , the exact same code i used for the pointers implementation is to be used by the array implementation. This means that when i am refercing to insertTree(tree,tree->left) must works for the array also .i am totally lost.
My node is:

```
    Typedef  struct BTNode{
     itemtype data;
      Struct BTNode * left;
     Struct BTNode * left;
    }BTNode;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the 'standard' case a new cell is supported by the result of a *malloc* and when it become useless you *free* it

Using an array can be to have an array of *BTNode* and rather than to *malloc* a new cell you get a free entry in the array. Because the cells can be get/released a priori in any order you can link the free cells too, so when a cell is released it is reintroduced in the free list associated to the array

So only the *malloc/free* calls have to be modified to be able to use an array or not

---

Note :

```
Typedef  struct BTNode{
     itemtype data;
      Struct BTNode * left;
     Struct BTNode * left;
    }BTNode;
```

you mean

```
typedef  struct BTNode{
   itemtype data;
   struct BTNode * left;
   struct BTNode * right;
} BTNode;
```

Comment: So if i understand correctly i am just using Malloc for an array of BTNodes . What's the purposes of this abstract type ? I mean its just like using the usual abstract type . Anyway thanks for the answer i will update the post for the furthermore issues.

Comment: not easy to use a abstract type in C, probably the best way is to use functions `BTNode * allocBTnode()` and `void freeBTNodes(BTNode *)` and to propose 2 definitions of them, one using malloc/free and the second the array, the choice between the 2 definitions can be done using the preprocessor (`#ifdef USEARRAY .. #else ... #endif`) to choose the one to use at compile time